# Kendo UI update edited data on grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I insert a new record (create), I can read the response from the server and update the grid with the new skillId.

To be able to do the same with the update (edit) function, I would need to find which row is being edited in order to update the skillId.
How can I determine what row is being updated? I could not find anyway of doing this yet.

```
            create: {
                url: "/admin/SkillProfessionCreate",
                contentType: "application/json",
                accepts: "application/json",
                type: 'POST',
                complete: function (e) {
                    var professionSkill = $.parseJSON(e.responseText);

                    var dataItem = dataSource.at(0);
                    dataItem.sklId = professionSkill.skillId;
                    $("#kendo").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
                }
            },
            update: {
                url: "/admin/SkillProfessionUpdate",
                contentType: "application/json",
                accepts: "application/json",
                type: 'POST',
                complete: function (e) {
                -- how to determine the row being update here?
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could go through the grid's Save event. There you have access to the databound item of the row being updated. See [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-save).

I think you should be able to achieve your purpose this way, by subscribing to the event and do whatever you need to do with the dataitem.